# Vertical viewport was given unbounded height using Single-Child-Scroll-View

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

When try to wrap "list view builder" with single-child-scroll-view it shows the given error.

Error : Vertical viewport was given unbounded height.

Also if I try to give a specific height of the list view wrapping with a container the single child scroll view doesn't work. It gives the same error. May be there are some faults in this code

Code :

```
          return ListView.builder(
              scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
              itemCount: dailyUpdate!.forecast!.forecastday!.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return Card(
                  elevation: 3,
                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
                  color: Color.fromARGB(255, 65, 65, 64),
                  child: Padding(
                    padding:
                        const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10, horizontal: 5),
                    child: Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                      children: [
                        Container(
                          width: 50,
                          child: Image.network(
                            'https:' +
                                dailyUpdate!.forecast!.forecastday![index].day!
                                    .condition!.icon
                                    .toString(),
                            width: 50,
                          ),
                        ),
                        Container(
                          width: 85,
                          child: customText(
                              DateFormat('EEE, MMMM d').format(DateTime.parse(
                                  dailyUpdate.forecast!.forecastday![index].date
                                      .toString())),
                              color: Colors.white),
                        ),
                        Container(
                          width: 120,
                          child: customText(
                              dailyUpdate.forecast!.forecastday![index].day!
                                  .condition!.text
                                  .toString(),
                              color: Colors.white),
                        ),
                        Container(
                          width: 60,
                          child: customText(
                              dailyUpdate.forecast!.forecastday![index].day!
                                      .maxtempC!
                                      .round()
                                      .toString() +
                                  ' / ' +
                                  dailyUpdate.forecast!.forecastday![index].day!
                                      .mintempC!
                                      .round()
                                      .toString(),
                              color: Colors.white),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              });
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem here is that the **SingleChildScrollView** provides unbound constraints in it's main axis.
Therefor it's child has infinite space available to size itself, but the **ListView** will by default expand to the available space which is now not possible(can't expand to infinite space).

Giving the **ListView** an explicit height (for example by wrapping it with a **Container** as you said, or using shrinkWrap) removes the Error. Where exactly did you put your Container?

Your best Solution would be to just remove the **SingleChildScrollView** completely, because it is unnecessary. The **ListView** already is scrollable on its own. If you want to control the scroll behaviour like for example making the scrollbar always visible, consider wrapping the **ListView** with a **Scrollbar** widget.

```
return Scrollbar(
  thumbVisibility: true,
  child: ListView.builder(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
    itemCount: 100,
    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) => Container(height: 50, color: Colors.blue[(index % 9) * 100]),
  ),
);
```